# excel vba cell linked to online stock data, want to trigger a macro whenever the cell value is updated

Tags: vba, excel

I have a cell which is linked to data from online tool and updated frequently. I want to trigger a macro whenever the cell value is updated.

I tried using `Worksheet_Calculate()`, it recalculate all the values not getting desired result and also tried `Worksheet_Change()`, it works fine when i manually change data, is there a solution for dynamic data change.

Answer (score 0):

Worksheet_Change only reacts to changes in formulas or hardcoded values (which you probably caused when you 'changed' cells by hand). Recalculations do not fire the change event. Instead, try using the Worksheet_Calculate() event:

```
Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    'Do stuff
End Sub
```